# How to bind to a public class function in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have been working on trying to get a button's context to display a string based off of a boolean value (i.e. "Insert" when bool is false and "Remove" when bool is true).  I wrote a simple function

```
public string MiniButtonText()
{
   if(GameInfo.IsMiniInserted == Visibility.Visible)
       return "Remove Mini";
   else
       return "Insert Mini";
}
```

that I want to call and have its return populate a button's context property.  How would I do this?  Also the function doesn't need to be called all the time, just when the IsMiniInserted property is changed.

The function is located inside my MainWindow class which is the window that I am currently running/using.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF does not support binding to methods

change that to a property:

```
public string MiniButtonText
{
   get
   {
       return GameInfo.IsMiniInserted == Visibility.Visible ? "Remove Mini" : "Insert Mini";
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that "does not support" does not mean "impossible". You can indirectly bind to methods using `ObjectDataProvider`, but certainly the easier solution here is binding to properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Property Instead with that simple calculation in it's getter. Fire the `PropertyChanged` on both properties when the `IsMiniInserted`value changes.